# The limit of the product with zero

Tags: calculus, limits

> Determine $$\lim_{x \to 2} \dfrac{(x-2)(f(x)^2+2g(x))}{(x^2-x-2)f(x)g(x)}$$ where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ are respectively $\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) =4$ and $\lim_{x \to 2} g(x) = 5$.

I want to solve this problem. The problem gets easier if you divide the numerator and the denominator by $(x-2)$, but is this allowed, and if so, why? Aren't you basically dividing by zero?

If it's not allowed, how else should you tackle this limit?

Comment: dividing by $(x-2)$ is allowed because for values near $2$, $(x-2)$ is nonzero, and for the limit we only care about values near $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we **don't** care about what happens **at** $x =2$, but at values "close" to $2$, when it comes to **limits**. (With continuity, this isn't the case.)

If you are familiar with the $\delta$-$\epsilon$ deifnition, this is why $0 < |x-2| < \delta$ for this specific problem; by inserting the $0<$ part of the definition, we specifically prohibit $x$ from equalling $2$.

By dividing both the numerator and denominator by $x-2$, you get
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 2}\dfrac{[f(x)]^2+2g(x)}{(x+1)f(x)g(x)}$$
and should be able to easily show that this is $\dfrac{16+10}{3(20)} = \dfrac{26}{60} = \dfrac{13}{30}$.